# Implement leaderboard database - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

My application has a main activity which starts two different activities. One is the main game and the other is the leaderboard. I have set up a SQLite database.

I need to be able to add a score to the database via the main game activity view and then read the data inside the leaderboard activity view. If I create the database in the main activity class, I can't access the database from the other activities. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I normally do is make a singleton class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and handles all database interaction.

```
private static String DB_NAME = DATABASE_NAME;

private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

private static DataBaseHelper databaseHelperInstance;
private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}
public static synchronized DataBaseHelper getInstance(Context c) {
    if (databaseHelperInstance == null) {
        synchronized (DataBaseHelper.class) {
            databaseHelperInstance = new DataBaseHelper(c);
        }
    }
    return databaseHelperInstance;
}
```

Then where you need it call for it:

```
DataBaseHelper.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());
```

This blog may be helpful:   http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html